# Modify the width of a cell with Xlwt in Django

Tags: python, django, excel

This is the code that i have right now in my views.py to download information of a template into an excel file:

```
def descarga(request,id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk= id_factura)
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    sheet = book.add_sheet('report')   
    alignment = xlwt.Alignment()

    alignment.horz = xlwt.Alignment.HORZ_LEFT
    alignment.vert = xlwt.Alignment.VERT_TOP
    style = xlwt.XFStyle() # Create Style
    style.alignment = alignment # Add Alignment to Style



    header_font = Font()

    # Header font preferences
    header_font.name = 'Times New Roman'
    header_font.height = 20 * 15
    header_font.bold = True

    # Header Cells style definition
    header_style = XFStyle()
    header_style.font = header_font 


    body_font = Font()

    # Body font preferences
    body_font.name = 'Arial'
    body_font.italic = True


    borders = Borders()
    borders.left = 1
    borders.right = 1
    borders.top = 1
    borders.bottom = 1
    header_style.borders = borders


    # body cell name style definition
    body_style = XFStyle()
    body_style.font = body_font 

    # write the header
    header = ['Cliente', 'Fecha de Factura', 'Tipo de Factura', 'Numero de Factura', 'Descripcion', 'Subtotal', 'IVA', 'Precio']
    for hcol, hcol_data in enumerate(header): # [(0,'Header 1'), (1, 'Header 2'), (2,'Header 3'), (3,'Header 4')]
    sheet.write(0, hcol, hcol_data, header_style)

    # write your data, you can also get it from your model

    data = {
        "Cliente": fact.nombre_cliente,
        "Fecha de Factura":fact.fecha_factura,
        "Tipo de Factura": fact.tipo_Factura,
        "Numero de Factura": fact.numero_De_Factura,
        "Descripcion": fact.descripcion,
        "Subtotal": fact.importe_sin_iva,
        "IVA": fact.iva,
        "Precio": fact.importe_Total,
        }

    for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
        sheet.write(1, column, str(data[key]), body_style)


    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.xls'
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

What i´m trying to do, without any success, is to increase the width of the columns to fit the information in them.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the content of header_style? Try to use

```
...
content_format   = 'align: wrap on'
sheet.write(0, hcol, hcol_data, ezxf(content_format))
...
```

And you can define width of your cell at the beginning by:

```
...
sheet.col(0).width = int(13*260)  
# 0 stands for col 0, 260 stands for 1mm so that this column's width is 13mm.
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is very helpfull. One more question: can i add font styles to that "content_format   = 'align: wrap on'"? because in "header_style" i have: "header_font.name = 'Times New Roman'
    header_font.height = 20 * 15
    header_font.bold = True". Thanks

Comment: @Nacho Yes, of course. 'font: bold on;align: wrap on', for instance.